# Spring boot application of kafka pipeline with error of "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available."

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

```
2020-02-26 18:08:54.925  WARN 4472 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

The following is the `application.yaml` file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        producer:
          useNativeEncoding: true
        consumer:
          useNativeEncoding: true
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: employee-details
          content-type: application/*+avro
          group: group-1
          concurrency: 3
        output:
          destination: employee-details
          content-type: application/*+avro
      kafka:
        binder:
          producer-properties:
            key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
          consumer-properties:
            key.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
            specific.avro.reader: true
```

I tried to run `curl -X POST https://localhost:9092/employees/1001/Harry/Potter` on cmd, but gave error of curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9092: Connection refused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding. `connect to localhost port 9092: Connection refused` Port 9092 is normally the Kafka port, not an HTTP port; given that you are getting `Broker may not be available.` and `Connection Refused` when trying to connect with curl implies you don't have Kafka running on `localhost` and you certainly can't connect to it with HTTP, even if it was running there.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I'm new to the framework, so do you mean to add bootstrap server in application.yml file under kafka?

Comment: I think I understand, I will try to make kafka run first.